# Contract classes

Tags: android, sqlite

I am new to android and I started reading the training lessons so I read the term contract classes [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html#) and I didn't fully understand what is it used for and how; What I understood is that if you created a class and added in it some public variables to be accessed from other classes that's a contract class, so basically there isn't a pre-created class named Contract it's just a description?!! I don't know if that's true so please if not let me know what is it used for and how, plus they also said:
To prevent someone from accidentally instantiating the contract class, give it an empty constructor.

Why do I need to do that, is it for the hackers not to play with my code or?!!
thanks.

Comment: post some lines of code which you think is causing you error. And also the LogCat for the error.

Comment: Quoting the page that you did not understand: "A contract class is a container for constants that define names for URIs, tables, and columns. The contract class allows you to use the same constants across all the other classes in the same package. This lets you change a column name in one place and have it propagate throughout your code."

Comment: @VeerShubhranshuShrivastav Did you read the question?

Comment: @CommonsWare I read this but I was asking if contract class is a definition or a real class what I think that it's just a definition...